# error running gzip in r

Tags: r, gzip

So I'm trying to compress a few gigs before transporting across the network.  I thought of "gzip" - my old favorite and it turns out that R.utils has it.

So installed it (Rstudio gui) and tried to compress the file.

```
gzip("my_honking_big_file.db")
```

Note, this was a mistake.  I should have used the following:

```
gzip("my_honking_big_file.db",remove=FALSE)
```

The error that was given was:

```
> gzip("test.db")
Warning message:
In nbytes + n : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

It made a zip file.

**Questions**:
What does the warning mean?  (Did I do something wrong?  Do I need to use a different zip to compress a file of that size?)

Is the resulting compressed file corrupted?